# Put filenames in directory into text file with specific parameters

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, cmd.exe

I need to put all filenames in directory (ideally excluding suffix) into text file. So far I'm using

```
dir /b > filex.txt
```

but I need to have output in one row and I need to have `OR` after every filename so I can easily copy these filenames and put them into Windows search.

The output in textfile should looks like this:

```
file OR file1 OR file2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another PowerShell answer:

```
(dir | % {$_.BaseName} | select -Unique) -join ' OR ' > outfile.txt
```

This gets all the objects in the current directory (`dir`), takes only their file title without extension (the `BaseName` property), removes duplicates (the `-Unique` flag of `select`), joins all of those together into one string delimited by  `OR` , and outputs it to `outfile.txt`. You won't get an extra "OR" at the end.

If you want all the names to be quoted, replace `$_.BaseName` with `'"' + $_.BaseName + '"'`. If you want to copy the finished string directly to the clipboard, replace the `>` and everything after it with `| Set-Clipboard`.

Save the script as a `.ps1` file. You'll need to follow the instructions in the Enabling Scripts section of [the PowerShell tag wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/powershell/info). Once that's done, you can run it from a batch file or command prompt like this:

```
powershell .\myscript.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind it on a separate line, you can use the below.

```
(get-childitem -path c:\test).basename | foreach-object {$_ -replace "$_", "$_ or "} >> c:\Filename.txt
```

This will get the files in c:\test. .basename removes the file type extension. The foreach replaces what is being piped through to what is being piped through with or after it.

Also please note, I have a space after the or. Remove that if you don't need it.

Hope this helps.

Thanks, Tim.